# Disable and enable with checkbox and simple form gem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form

I'm trying to disable and enable action with checkbox on the post form. 
And I don't know much about javascript or JQuery. 
And I'm trying to do this action a lot and I don't how to do it, I'm programming alone.

So if anyone could help me with this, I will appreciate!
I'm using a Rails 4.2.8 and jquery-rails-4.3.1 versions.

my form: `app/views/posts/_form.html.slim`

```
 = simple_form_for(@post, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|    = f.input :publish,
             label: "Publish?",
             as: :boolean,
             label_html: { class: "publish-check" },
             input_html: { checked: false },
             remote: true    = f.input :published_at, disabled: true, hint: 'You cannot publish your post.',label: "Publish Post at:"
```

I'm trying to put this on the file`app/assets/javascript/_form.coffee` it's alright or I need to put on another file?

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  $checkbox = $('[id^="post_publish"]')
  $select = $('.post_published_at')
  $checkbox.change (e) ->
    $select.prop 'disabled', !$checkbox.is(':checked')
    return
  return
```

This field published_at it's a date time.
So I think now I need to put some array, the id's generated it's like`id="post_published_at_1i"` and until `id="post_published_at_5i"`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, the only way of doing that is with javascript:

```
= simple_form_for(@post, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
   = f.input :publish, label: "Publish?", as: :boolean, input_html: { checked: false }
   = f.input :published_at, label: "Publish Post at", style: "visibility: hidden;"
```

That will create something like the HTML part below, so, you just need to add the javascript to your page and maybe tweak it a little bit.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.getElementById('post_publish').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('post_published_at')
    if (this.checked) {
      input.style.visibility = 'visible';
      input.disabled = false;
    } else {
      input.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      input.disabled = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="new_post" action="/post" method="post">
  <input id="post_publish" type="checkbox">
  <label>Publish?</label>
  <input id="post_published_at" style="visibility: hidden;">
</form>
```

Comment: I just watching now and the way hidden isn't good choice it's better with the display: none and then with javascript put display: block. because if it isn't checked I don't want any value for submit the field published_at

Comment: thank you for reply @luisenrike, I edit the code for reply your code because I have an error and here is so small to put it all. I don't now much javascript and this code I try throws an error.